# R ggplot only shows one bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, readxl

I am just starting to work with R, so apologies if my question is too basic,
I have an excel sheet , here's the link: https://file.io/LfsAOdDCVnFq

where I am trying to plot a simple bar plot as follows:

`X` = I want it to be my sample names , the column called `OTU ID` in the file
`Y` = I want it to be the sum of my variables for each sample, column called Sum ZOTUs in the file

so far, I have installed and called library of ggplot2 and tried to plot my data frame but when I do that it only shows one bar, and I don't know what is wrong

```
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("ggplot2")

library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

ZOTU <- read_excel(file.choose())

ggplot(data=ZOTU, aes(x="OTU ID")) + geom_bar ()
```

and it shows the plot below:

[image]

can anyone help how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried replacing the quotes (`"`) by backticks (`)?

Comment: equivalently, you can replace `aes` by `aes_string` to use a quoted column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your uploaded image with the excel sheet screenshot.

My guess would be using quotation marks instead of backticks. Try running this code:

```
ggplot(data = ZOTU, aes(x = `OTU ID`)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try

Execute this code in your computer, and see if it helps you understand how `ggplot` works:

```
library(ggplot2) # load ggplot
mpg # let's look at a 'mpg' data included in the ggplot package

# Now, a simple bar plot
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = fl)) +
  geom_bar()
```

We use the mpg data as the data for our figure, and we set the x-axis to be the `fl` column of that data. Finally, we "add" a bar plot to the figure.
By default, the bar plot will plot the count of the different values present in the column you passed as x-axis.

### After comments

Following our discussion in the comment section, maybe this is what you want.
If you have the names (discrete variable) for the x-axis in a column, and another column with the variable you want to sum and plot in y for each name, try:

```
ggplot(data = mpg) +
  geom_col(aes(x = manufacturer, y = hwy))
```

You can have the values with the code

```
library(tidyverse)
 mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% summarize(total = sum(hwy))
```

So for your case, if you have a column with the names you want in the x-axis, and another with the values you want the code to sum for each name, use

```
ggplot(data = your_data_frame) +
  geom_col(aes(x = your_names, y = values_to_be_summed_for_each_name))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to better formulate my questions letter, I looked at the mpg data, but when I try to run head(mpg) it displays "p" as values for fl column so I am a bit confused where in the fl column are the different values?

Comment: `head(mpg)` will show you only the first lines of the data, run `View(mpg)` to see more (in RStudio). The `mpg` data is commonly used for examples and it describes car models and their fuel consumption. The "fl" column stands for "fuel type" and it has the values "p" "r" "e" "d" or "c". If you do a bar plot of the "fl" column, you will get the possible values in the x-axis and the counts (the number of times each value was present in the data) as the y-axis.
Try changing `aes(x = the_colum_name_you_want_to_see)` to explore other columns and better understand how it works

Comment: For your question, find what is the name of the column you want to have in the x-axis. If it has spaces, use backticks to state the name, as @edv said (but I think quotes or double quotes could also work).

Comment: As a side note, you marked this answer as the answer to your question, but I don't think it did. The answer was just meant to give some advice and a starting point to solve your problem (as I don't have the data to work on).

Comment: ah right! thanks, I see now and yes the backticks worked as well, I think a little bit of problem is that my data is quite large, about 13000 columns, so when I want to plot the sum of them all, there are more than 130000 values and it kinda crashes, as they are all very different so it gives me a quite weird figure with very small lines stacked together, but I am not planning on showing all the data, I just wanted to learn how to do bar plots with a single axis, thanks again!

Comment: Given your last comment, I think you want to use a `geom_col()` then. If you have the names (discrete variable) for the x-axis in a column, and another column with the variable you want to sum (in your case a column of the sum of all other variables, if I understand correctly) then use the new code in my revised answer.
Also, R can handle large datasets, I don't think you can crash it with your data

Comment: If the edited answer solves your question, then you can mark the answer as the correct one again.

Comment: As I understand you are working with microbial data, so this might not be the best way to deal with such large data. Often you would check unique OTUs found per sample rather than counts for each OTU or convert OTU counts to relative abundances for comparison. You should check tutorial for ampvis2 package that has the functions and examples for analysing such data (https://madsalbertsen.github.io/ampvis2/index.html).